# How to upgrade Spotify to 0.8.8?

Tags: spotify

We realized that in our development team we have inconsistent Spotify versions. One part has 0.8.8 whereas the other part is having the old version - 0.8.5. Spotify is not upgrading for the accounts with the old version. However, apparently there are changes to the Spotify API, so that our app runs on 0.8.5 but not on 0.8.8. How can the other developers update to 0.8.8 as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current production Spotify API framework should be the latest, regardless of the client version. 
Right now it's ver. 0.2.8.

Remember that you need to declare your framework dependencies inside your manifest file. You can read more about it here:

https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/integration/#frameworks

0.8.5 is still the current live client, while 0.8.8 is gradually rolling out to a few users.

There is a preview API which depends on the bridge changes made in 0.8.8, but it shouldn't be used for production yet.

https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/preview/